# How could my custom Symfony ChoiceType allow extra items?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm working on a `TagField` for EasyAdmin 4 (and Symfony 6) that will rely on a `TagType`. This `TagType` will have the native `ChoiceType` as a parent.

This field will be rendered as a multiple `select`, with these attributes to allow adding tags on the fly:

```php
[ 'data-ea-widget' => 'ea-autocomplete', 'data-ea-autocomplete-allow-item-create' => 'true' ]
```

To do so, I created a `TagListener`. Its main goal is to prefill the options with the already existing tags (on other entities) to support tag suggestion. After reading the docs and many articles, I chose to listen to the `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` event.

Unfortunately there does not seem to be an easy way to "override" the default options, and we're left with having to override the entire field.

Here's what the `TagListener` looks like:

```php
<?php
// src/Form/EventListener/TagListener.php

namespace eduMedia\TagBundle\Form\EventListener;

use eduMedia\TagBundle\Entity\TaggableInterface;
use eduMedia\TagBundle\Form\Type\TagType;
use eduMedia\TagBundle\Service\TagService;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class TagListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function __construct(private TagService $tagService)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData',
        ];
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event): void
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $parentForm = $event->getForm()->getParent();
        /** @var TaggableInterface $taggable */
        $taggable = $parentForm->getData();

        // We retrieve the existing options to override some of them
        $options = $form->getConfig()->getOptions();

//         if ($options['pre_set_data_called']) {
//            return;
//        }

        // We prefill options with the existing tags for this resource type
        $allTagNames = $this->tagService->getTypeTagNames($taggable->getTaggableType());

        // They are our new choices
        $options['choices'] = array_combine($allTagNames, $allTagNames);
        
        // We also need to select the entity's tags
        $options['data'] = $this->tagService->loadTagging($taggable)->getTagNames($taggable);
        
        // We override the form field
//        $options['pre_set_data_called'] = true;
        $parentForm->add($form->getName(), TagType::class, $options);
    }

}
```

Doing so seems to create an infinite loop, where `onPreSetData` is called when calling `$parentForm->add()`. Is that normal? Is `PRE_SET_DATA` dispatched again when adding a field in a listener? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I tried adding a `pre_set_data_called` form option, setting it to `true` when calling `$parentForm->add()` and exiting the listener when it is indeed `true`. It kind of works, but then I get this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Field "tags" has already been rendered, save the result of previous render call to a variable and output that instead.").

How can I manage to allow extra items in my custom field type?

For reference, here is my `TagType` class:

```php
<?php

namespace eduMedia\TagBundle\Form\Type;

use eduMedia\TagBundle\Form\EventListener\TagListener;
use eduMedia\TagBundle\Service\TagService;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TagType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct(private TagService $tagService)
    {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new TagListener($this->tagService));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'mapped'   => false,
            'multiple' => true,
//            'pre_set_data_called' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

}
```

And my `TagField` class:

```php
<?php

namespace eduMedia\TagBundle\Admin\Field;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;
use eduMedia\TagBundle\Form\Type\TagType;

class TagField implements FieldInterface
{

    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null)
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(TagType::class)
            ->setFormTypeOption('attr', [ 'data-ea-widget' => 'ea-autocomplete', 'data-ea-autocomplete-allow-item-create' => 'true' ])
            ->setTemplatePath('@eduMediaTag/fields/tag.html.twig')
            ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the `ChoiceType` as the parent (`<select>` element), but rather the `TextType` (`<input type=text>` element), and splitting/exploding a simple string.

The actual bundle is live on [GitHub](https://github.com/edumedia-sciences/tag-bundle) and even though it might not be perfect (yet ), the implementation is way simpler and the end-user behaviour is exactly what I expected.